# Index value confusion in python

Tags: python

Hey all am new to python programming and i have noticed some code which is really confusing me.

```
import collectors
   s = 'mississippi'
d = collectors.defaultdict(int)
 for k in s:


d[k] += 1

d.items()
```

The thing i need to know is the use of d[k] here ..I know k is the value in the string s.But i didnt understood  what d[k] returns.In defaultdict(int) new value is created if dictonary has no values..

Please help me any help would be appreciated ..Thanks ..

Comment: The indentation in the question is thoroughly broken. Since whitespace is significant in Python, you should edit to fix that up. I suspect this isn't the source of your issues, but it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: Not only is the indentation off, but it should be `collections.defaultdict`, not `collectors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python are "mapping" types. (This applies to both regular `dict` dictionaries and the more specialized variations like `defaultdict`.) A mapping takes a key and "maps" it to a value. The syntax `d[k]` is used to look up the key `k` in the dictionary `d`. Depending on where it appears in your code, it can have slightly different semantics (either returning the existing value for the key or setting a new one).

In your example, you're using `d[k] += 1`, which increments the value under key `k` in the dictionary. Since integers are immutable, it actually breaks out into `d[k] = d[k] + 1`. The right side `d[k]` does a look up of the value in the dictionary. Then it adds one and, using the `d[k]` on the left side, assigns the result into the dictionary as a new value.

`defaultdict` changes things a bit in that keys that don't yet exist in the dictionary are treated as if they did exist. The argument to its constructor is a "factory" object which will be called to create the new values when an unknown key is requested.

Comment: so what will be the value of d here ?

Comment: I would transfer my 'accept' to you because you deserve it, but all I can do is give you an upvote

Comment: so in d[k]+1 the value of the corresponding values of the key are incremented one by one right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
d[key]
Return the item of d with key key. Raises a KeyError if key is not in the map.
```

Straigth from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), under mapping types.

Go to https://docs.python.org/ and bookmark it. It will become your best friend.

Comment: Nope. Wrong kind of dict. OP is apparently using [collectors.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: didnt get you ?..what is the key ?..is key mean the value of k ?

Comment: @Carsten He is, but dict and defaultdict behave the same in this situation. from your link: `It overrides one method and adds one writable instance variable. The remaining functionality is the same as for the dict class`

Comment: @user3501595 key is what they call it in the python docs. In your code, it is k

Comment: @TimCastelijns No they don't. That's the whole point of `defaultdict`. Here's what happens if you create a defaultdict` with a `default_factory` which is not `None`: _"If default_factory is not None, it is called without arguments to provide a default value for the given key, this value is inserted in the dictionary for the key, and returned."_

Comment: @Carsten ah right. I didn't see this `This method is called by the __getitem__() method of the dict class when the requested key is not found`. You are right

Comment: @TimCastelijns got it ..and the thing is that i just need to know what d[k] plays a role ?..can you please explain me...

Comment: suppose if d is 10 ..so it returns 10[k] ..??

Comment: No, `d` is your dictionary. You can say `d[10]` and it will return the value that belongs to key `10`

Comment: so in d[k]+1 the value of the corresponding values of the key are incremented one by one right ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns If you edit your answer, I can retract the downvote. :)

Comment: @Carsten so here the key and the value of the dictionary increments  by 1 ..right ??...

Comment: @user3501595 You seem to be lacking conceptual knowledge about Python dictionaries, more than I could explain to you in a comment. Please [read the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: i just want to know yes or no ..is what is told right ?...did the value of corresponding key increment by 1 ?

Comment: Why don't you just open up an interpreter and try it out? Most of the times that is the easiest way to find out

Comment: i have checked ..but i didnt got it ..can you tell me if its value increments by 1 ?